# What's the difference between Reliability, Resiliency, and Robustness?

Tags: machine-learning, definitions

In the context of the Machine Learning model, is there any clear definition of reliability, resiliency, and robustness of a model? I saw some papers discuss different things (e.g. attacked model, fault model, noisy data, etc.) when they talk about these terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this guy's thesis](https://kilthub.cmu.edu/articles/thesis/Towards_Robust_and_Resilient_Machine_Learning/19552420) to be very helpful in understanding it:

- **Robustness: The model can be trained even with noisy and corrupted data.** Simply put, if we add small perturbations to the image, can it still recognize it correctly? This one is important in Adversarial attack, where an attacker *purposely* adds the pertubation to misguide the models.
- **Reliability: After training and when deployed in the real-world, the model should not break down under benign shifts of the distribution**. This is straightforward to understand: how good the model is on a set that has different distribution than the training set, e.g., I train on photos but evaluate on paintings.
- **Resilience: The modeling procedure should work under model mis-specification**, i.e. even when the modeling assumption breaks down, the model should find the best possible solution. For example, when the hardware breaks, can the model still perform as good?

Comment: I see, it's a great lead, thank you!